# How to import a figma animation into rive?

Tags: figma, rive, figma-plugin

I know that I can import a figma design by exporting as an svg and importing by copy/paste in assets folder of rive editor.
But can we import a whole component with it animation?
Thank you?

Comment: [check out the documentation](https://help.rive.app/editor/fundamentals/importing-assets)